# Padding in Ionic Slider

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

sorry for beginner question in html,css and ionic. I have problem with padding.

I want have image slider like this [image: My Requirements]

But with my codes i got this:
[image]

I want the text and image in red box get up like in first image. I have trying using minus for padding-top and using css in ionic but doesn't work

Here is my code:

```
 <ion-view view-title="Example">
  <ion-content class="padding">
   <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="false" auto-play="true" does-continue="true">
          <ion-slide>
              <h3>Favourite</h3>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-back col col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                    <span class="row">
                        <img src="img/pizza1.jpg" class="col col-50" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                        <div class="col col-50" style="; padding-top:-10px">
                            <h4 class="row">Image One </h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="img/star.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px; padding-top:-10px"class="col col-40">
                                <h4 class="col col-60" style="padding-top:-10px"> 5.0</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-forward col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
           <h3>Favourite</h3>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-back col col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                    <span class="row">
                        <img src="img/pizza2.jpg" class="col col-50" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                        <div class="col col-50" style="; padding-top:-10px">
                            <h4 class="row">Image Two </h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="img/star.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px; padding-top:-10px"class="col col-40">
                                <h4 class="col col-60"> 5.0</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-forward col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
          <h3>Favourite</h3>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-back col col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                    <span class="row">
                        <img src="img/pizza3.jpg" class="col col-50" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                        <div class="col col-50" style="; padding-top:-10px">
                            <h4 class="row">Image Three </h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="img/star.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px; padding-top:-10px"class="col col-40">
                                <h4 class="col col-60"> 5.0</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <div class="ion-ios-arrow-forward col-5" style="padding-top:50px;"/></div>
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also i have try modify ionic.app.css using this but doesn't work:

```
<div class="row row-up">

 .row-up{
  padding:-10px; }
 }
```

Thanks...

Comment: You can't do negative `padding`. Try `margin-top: -10px` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much :) it is work, 
Sorry i am very new in web programming never do html,css,js before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as negative `padding`. Try `margin-top: -10px` instead.

[image]